# check if numpy array is multidimensional or not

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if a numpy array is multidimensional or not?

```
V = [[ -7.94627203e+01  -1.81562235e+02  -3.05418070e+02  -2.38451033e+02][  9.43740653e+01   1.69312771e+02   1.68545575e+01  -1.44450299e+02][  5.61599000e+00   8.76135909e+01   1.18959245e+02  -1.44049237e+02]]
```

How can I do that in numpy?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use the [`.ndim`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html) property of the ndarray:

```
>>> a = np.array([[ -7.94627203e+01,  -1.81562235e+02,  -3.05418070e+02,  -2.38451033e+02],[  9.43740653e+01,   1.69312771e+02,   1.68545575e+01,  -1.44450299e+02],[  5.61599000e+00,   8.76135909e+01,   1.18959245e+02,  -1.44049237e+02]])
>>> a.ndim
2
```

Answer (score 7):

In some cases, you should also add `np.squeeze()` to make sure there are no "empty" dimensions

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3]])
>>> a.ndim
2
>>> a = np.squeeze(a)
>>> a .ndim
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.23/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html?highlight=numpy%20ndarray%20shape#numpy.ndarray.shape) property too, which gives you a tuple containing the **length of each dimension**. Therefore, to get the dimension using `.shape` you could aswell call `len()` on the resulting tuple:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[1,2,3]])
c = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,4,6],[3,6,9]])

print("a={}".format(a))
print("a.shape: {}; len(a.shape): {}".format(a.shape, len(a.shape)))

print("b={}".format(b))
print("b.shape: {}; len(b.shape): {}".format(b.shape, len(b.shape)))

print(c)
print("c.shape: {}; len(c.shape): {}".format(c.shape, len(c.shape)))
```

Output:

```
a=[1 2 3]
a.shape: (3,); len(a.shape): 1
b=[[1 2 3]]
b.shape: (1, 3); len(b.shape): 2
[[1 2 3]
 [2 4 6]
 [3 6 9]]
c.shape: (3, 3); len(c.shape): 2
```