# get "1" for a one-dimensional numpy.array using a shape-like function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, dimension

In a function, I give a Numpy array : It can be multi-dimentional but also one-dimentional

So when I give a multi-dimentional array :

```
np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]).shape
>>> (3, 4)
```

and

```
np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]).shape[1]
>>> 4
```

Fine.

But when I ask the shape of

```
np.array([1,2,3,4]).shape
>>> (4,)
```

and

```
np.array([1,2,3,4]).shape[1]
>>> IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Ooops, the tuple contain only one element... while I want `1` to indicate it is a one-dimentional array.
Is there a way to get this ? I mean with a simple function or method, and without a discriminant test with `ndim` for exemple ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if numpy array is multidimensional or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299798/check-if-numpy-array-is-multidimensional-or-not)

Comment: your array is clearly 1-dim, it wouldn't make sense to ask for its other dimensions. you'd need a matrix such as `np.array([[1,2,3,4]]).shape` (1, 4)

Comment: (or `np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]]).shape`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.ndim
1
>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
>>> b.ndim
2
```

If you wanted a column vector, you can use the `.reshape` method - in fact, `.shape` is actually a settable property so numpy also lets you do this:

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.shape += (1,)
>>> a
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>> a.shape
(4, 1)
>>> a.ndim
2
```

Comment: Does this resetting allow the array to still be contiguous?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there is no way to set default value for accessing list element, but you can try:

```
>>> shape = np.array([1,2,3,4]).shape
>>> shape[1] if shape[1:] else 1
1
```

HTH.